# Is there a way to handle a https forwarding to http without a browser error message?

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, https, ssl-certificate, forwarding

Scenario:
We have two domains, example.com (used as simple Webpage) and example.de (used as a Shop).
The Shop was secured with a ssl certificate und used https connection. We closed the Shop and want to forward all existing links to example.com Webpage. The SSL Certificate was delivered via the shop provider and isn't accessible anymore.

We used a simple rewite rule to catch all requested uris and forward them to example.com

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bikers-base.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this triggers a browser message when you try to follow old https links.

I've read that because there is no certificate, the browser cannot establish a connection and send http requests.

Is there any way to bypass this behavior via mod_rewrite or another way? Glad if I could get some help.

Comment: You can not solve this with mod-rewite or any other redirection methods. You need to buy a valid ssl cert for your domain in order to redirect https URLs back to http.

Comment: This is not related to htaccess or mod_rewrite. It's a safety of web browsers and there is not any way to bypass this.